# Jquery - filter on a Array

Tags: jquery, filter

I'm trying to filter some elements for a simple category filter based on the following simplified code:

```
<div class="filter">
    <ul class="marchi-filter">
        <li class="filter active" data-rel="data-all">Tutti i settori</li>
        <li class="filter" data-rel="data-13">Carrozzeria</li>
        <li class="filter" data-rel="data-14">Edilizia</li>
        <li class="filter" data-rel="data-16">Fai da te</li>
        <li class="filter" data-rel="data-15">Industria</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="marchio-detail clearfix" data-filter="data-14|data-16|data-15">
    data-14 data-16 data-15
    </div>
       <div class="marchio-detail clearfix" data-filter="data-14|data-15">
    data-14 data-15
    </div>
       <div class="marchio-detail clearfix" data-filter="data-16">
    data-16 
    </div>
       <div class="marchio-detail clearfix" data-filter="data-16|data-15">
    data-16 data-15
    </div>
       <div class="marchio-detail clearfix" data-filter="data-14">
    data-14 
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following js code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".filter").on("click", function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                // if we click the active tab, do nothing
                if (!$this.hasClass("active")) {
                    $(".filter").removeClass("active");
                    $this.addClass("active");
                    // set the active tab
                    // get the data-rel value from selected tab and set as filter
                    var $filter = $this.data("rel");
                    //// if we select view all, return to initial settings and show all
                    $filter == 'data-all' ?
                            $(".marchio-detail")
                            .not(":visible")
                            .fadeIn(500)
                    :
                            // otherwise
                            $(".marchio-detail")
                            .fadeOut(500)
                            .filter(function() {
                                var $datalist = $(this).data("filter").split("|");
                                console.log($(this).inArray($datalist, $filter) > -1);
                                return $(this).inArray($datalist, $filter) > -1;
                            })
                            .fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        });
```

I had splitted the data-filter in to a Array but the combination of .filter() and .inArray() is a bit complicated to understand for me.

I really appreciate if somebody can point me out where is the culprit. Thanks!

Comment: Culprit for what? What isn't working? What do you expect, and what actually happens?

Comment: So... this doesn't work?  What does it do?  What do you want it to do?  "Culprit" for what?  You haven't told us what's wrong here.

Comment: Your `inArray` is backwards.  The first argument is supposed to be the value you are looking for.  The second is the array containing values.

Comment: Sorry for not explain correctly my problem: I need to filter the $("marchio-detail") with the data-rel corrispective clicked on the "marchi-filter" unordered list above. I can't figure out how to filter correctly the items in $datalist Array. Hope I explained better. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

```
$(".filter").on("click", function() {
```

should really be

```
$(".marchi-filter").on("click",'li', function () {
```

so that your `this` variable refers to the `li` elements (*the ones that hold the `data-rel` attributes. In your case you had the external `.filter` element that messed things up*)

---

Secondly your `inArray` is backwards. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/ for more info

---

Last, when you filter to avoid hiding everything and then showing your filtered results, you could just hide then ones that need hiding and show the ones that need showing..

So your *otherwise* should become

```
var all =  $(".marchio-detail"),
    active = all.filter(function () {
        var $datalist = $(this).data("filter").split("|");
        return $.inArray($filter, $datalist) > -1;
    })
all.not(active).fadeOut(500);
active.fadeIn(500);
```

Demo with all changes at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/LfSsb/

Comment: You helped me a lot Gaby, Thanks a lot. Really appreciate!

Comment: Anyway, can you explain me better why you added the li element in the click function? Thanks!

Comment: @Funkwarrior this is the concept of delegated event handling. A parent element handles the events that occur in its child elements (*read more at http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events*)